# Converting C# Razor to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, razor

I am new to Razor view syntax and as most of the examples are in C# I need help in coverting the below Razor syntax to vb.net.

```
@helper selected (string c,string culture)
{
    if (c==culture)
    {
        @:checked='checked'
    }
}
```

Comment: Razor is the view engine - which consists of the @helper and @: syntax. Your question refers to translating C# to VB.Net INSIDE a Razor view.

Comment: @Spikeh There are different Razor syntaxes depending on whether you're using C# or VB.Net. Razor code can go in a .vbhtml file or a .cshtml file, and which one you use determines which syntax must be used. In VB.Net, curly braces are not used to delimit blocks of *Razor* code. To be clear, the question should say "converting the below Razor C# syntax to Razor VB.Net syntax," but it's not far off the mark in asking the appropriate question.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting C#.Net to VB.Net inside a razor view:

```
@helper selected (c As String, culture As String)
    If c = culture Then
        @:checked='checked'
    End If
End helper
```

I haven't touched VB.Net for years, but it looks like that should work for you.

Comment: This is correct but I was wondering if anyone here is aware of any online tools to convert razor view quickly from C# to VB and vise versa? I'm kind of tired of doing this by hand... :) I understand that razor views include html which has nothing to do with C# and VB but it would be nice if I could just paste the entire view and get a converted view as an output...

Answer (score 0):

From ASP.NET:

"The Razor syntax is based on the C# programming language, and that's the language that's used most often with ASP.NET Web Pages. **However, the Razor syntax also supports the Visual Basic language**, and everything you see you can also do in Visual Basic. For details, see the appendix Visual Basic Language and Syntax."

Here are some examples in VB.NET that can help you:

[Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (Visual Basic)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28vb%29)